# background in TD

Tags: html, css

this is what I want to achieve:

[image]

I was operating with "position: absolute" and so on, but the red line now hides the numbers

```
<td class="centerText">
    <div class="relative">
    <div style="position: absolute; z-index: 0; background-color: red; width: 
        <?php echo rand(1,100); ?>%;">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <?php echo $rec['VOTENUM']; ?>
</td>
```

Comment: okay, question was edited

Comment: as long as you're using position it will overlap the numbers because the positioned elements are out of the document folw

Comment: then what should I use instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZRN5C/)

```
<table>
   <tr>
       <td><div style="background-color: red; width: 30%">5</div></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td><div style="background-color: red; width: 50%">4</div></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

You create a div inside each cell and set his width. The text will be inside the div.

Answer (score 0):

Does this hepls:

```
<td class="centerText">
    <div class="relative" style="text-align:right">
    <div style="position: absolute; z-index: 0; background-color: red; width: 
        <?php echo rand(1,100); ?>%;">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <?php echo $rec['VOTENUM']; ?>
</td>
```

I added `style="text-align:right"`

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to remove the position, try this solution:

**HTML:**

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="bar" style="width:<?php echo rand(1,100); ?>%;">
        </div> <?php echo $rec['VOTENUM']; ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="bar" style="width:<?php echo rand(1,100); ?>%;">
        </div> <?php echo $rec['VOTENUM']; ?>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
td {
height:25px;
border:1px solid #000;
width:300px;
}
.bar {
display:inline-block;
background:red;
height:20px;
}
```

**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Karim_AG/CR7yv/)**.